# SystemVerilog randc reinitialization

Tags: random, verilog, verification, system-verilog

I was wondering if there is a way to reinitialize a randc variable.  I am trying to set several registers, but need to make sure they can be set in arbitrary order.  This object may get re-randomized (there are some other random values in the class), and then the function may get called again.  My code looks something like this:

```
typedef enum bit[N:0] { REG1, REG2, REG3, REG4, ... } reg_order_e;
local randc reg_order_e reg_order;

function void set_regs();
    repeat( reg_order.num() ) begin
        case( reg_order )
            REG1: set_reg1();
            REG2: set_reg2();
            REG3: set_reg3();
            REG4: set_reg4();
        endcase
        assert(randomize( reg_order ));
    end
endfunction : set_regs
```

Alternatively, is there a way of calling std::randomize() on a variable to make it a randc? 
Thanks,
-Tim

Comment: What problem are you seeing with your current code? It should properly iterate over all values in `reg_order_e` in a randc manner.

Comment: How would the randsequence guarantee that every register gets hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution based on some comments on the verification academy forum where I posted the same [question](http://verificationacademy.com/forum/verification-methodology-discussion-forum/systemverilog-and-other-languages-forum/28155-reinitializing-randc).  Basically, to achieve what I want, I need to create a new class with its own random variable

```
class helper;
     randc reg_order_e reg_order;
endclass : helper

task do_some_work();
    helper helper_inst = new();
    repeat( reg_order_e.num() ) begin
        assert( helper_inst.randomize() );
        case( helper_inst.reg_order )
            REG1: ...
            REG2: ...
        endcase
    end
endtask : do_some_work
```